# Cross validation for linear models in R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am trying to do cross validation of a linear model in R using cv.lm. I have tried capturing the output from cv.lm in a separate variable using something like:

**cvOutput <- cv.lm(.....)**

However, I cannot extract the predicted values from every fold as **cvOutput** seems to have no information about folds. Is there any way of extracting this?

Comment: the documentation literally says `Each fold is removed`

Comment: Yes, I know that. The question then is whether there's an alternative function in another package that I can use to capture this information?

Comment: You can do the cross validation using a for loop which will allow you to assign the result of each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. (I used Caravan dataset from MASS package for example)
First your partition the data

```
df <- Caravan
inTrain <- createDataPartition(df$Purchase, 
                           p =0.8, 
                           list =F)
training <- df[ inTrain,]
testing <- df[-inTrain,]
```

Then you choose the method

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
```

Then you can have your cross validated model

```
fit <- train(Purchase ~ ., 
         data = training, 
         method = "lm", 
         trControl = fitControl)
```